# Different results in Code::Blocks and Ideone for the same piece of code

Tags: c

I tried to run this piece of code from the K&R book to count the number of characters in input:

```
int main()
{
    int count=0;
    while(getchar()!=EOF)
        count++;
        printf("%d",count);
return 0;
    }
```

I did not get any output in Code::Blocks since every time after processing each character of input separately, **getchar** again asks for a new input due to the while loop, and control doesn't proceed to the print line. Then, why am I getting the desired output on Ideone. For example, if I enter Hello, it gives output 5 instead of asking for a new input. What is the problem here?

Comment: How do you give the Codeblocks version the EOF command? That's likely the problem. Pressing enter does not result in EOF.

Comment: As @Lundin said, you cannot provide EOF by pressing enter. What you can try is write your input in a file and pipe the input into the executable while executing. You can try `a.exe < file.txt` where file.txt has the string you want to give as input.

Comment: Otherwise, some systems also accept ctr+d as EOF in input.

Answer (score 1):

The `getchar()` function returns `EOF` **when input fails**.  It does not mean that it read an "EOF character" or something like that.  You should not think of EOF as meaning "end-of-file" in this context.

When you ran the program from Code::Blocks, you never did anything to cause input to fail. So input never failed, so your loop conditional was always true.

When ideone runs the program, it uses the input you supplied when you ran the program as input.  When that input has all been processed, trying to get more input fails and therefore the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment section you can not reach `EOF` by pressing the enter.
One way to get out of the while loop is that you write some `if` statement with a `break` as following example when you press `space` it will go out of the loop.
The other way is just press `Ctrl + d` to get out of the loop.

```
int main(){
 int count=0;
    while(getchar()!=EOF){
       count++;
    if(getchar() == ' '){
      break;
      }
    printf("%d",count);
   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you are telling is fine. But what I really want to ask is: why did my code give output on Ideone. How did it understand that I only wanted to type 12345 (say, for example) and did not ask for further input, while Code::Blocks asked for further input for the same code (due to the looping mechanism)? Is it a problem with Ideone?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, I have tested it from command line and Code blocks so both of them give me the same result. I 'm not familiar with Ideone how it interpret code.

Comment: In ideone, you specify the input in a buffer beforr you execute the program. So it knows that no more input is coming. It signals end of stream by inserting a EOF. In your console, you can type anything you want. When will the console insert the EOF? How will it know when you are done typing? Either if you take the input from a file which has fixed length of content, or if you explicitly signal end of input using ctr+d

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    while(getchar() != '\t') // If tab is entered we break
    {
       count++; // iterate
       printf("%d\n", count); // print counter
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Console will stop asking for input when you'll input a tab. But the prints will only be printed when the loop is exited.

EDIT :

I think Ideone has a particular way to handle EOF. It seems like Ideone aumatically puts EOF when it has computed everything in the output text area. I found no way to reproduce EOF manually, even by writing `\n`. However using a character as a way to exit the loop seems to work correctly.

I don't know if it can help you, but I found this in Ideone's FAQ.

[image]

Comment: Then why does it give output on Ideone? That is my major doubt.

Comment: With this very code, when I input `Hello\t` (`\t`being tab), it outputs `1 2 3 4 5`. What about you ?

Comment: No, I meant the code which i wrote (i.e.where I used EOF). Your code is fine. I'm asking why did my code give output on Ideone. How did it understand that I only wanted to type 12345 (say, for example) and did not ask for further input, while Code::Blocks asked for further input for the same code (due to the looping mechanism)? Please help, if you know.

Comment: @HarshitR I edited my answer. Please let me know if it helped you in anyway.

Comment: You highlighted EOL, but OP is asking about EOF

Comment: Yep. As I precised it, I don't know if it can be useful, but may be it will.